# how can i change the color/size of google map markers in tomchent google-react-maps?

Tags: reactjs

currently working on react-google-maps,
i need random colors of map markers for different locations

```
 const MyMapComponent = compose(
        withProps({
        googleMapURL:
       "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyB-
       lALSE8L0zgfk0vdt73gNTsfalkAggwY&v=3.exp&libraries=geometry
      ,drawing,places",
       loadingElement: <div style={{ height: "100%" }} />,
       containerElement: <div style={{width:"100%", height: ht,}} />,
       mapElement: <div style={{ height: "100%"}} />
       }),
      withScriptjs,
      withGoogleMap
      )(props => (
    <GoogleMap defaultZoom={10} defaultCenter={{ lat: 32.6804468, 
  lng: -97.0827933 }}>
   <Marker  position={{ lat: 32.4695839, lng: -97.0587439 }} />
   <Marker  position={{ lat: 32.5645087, lng: -97.1868373}} />
   <Marker  position={{ lat: 33.2076922, lng: -97.396451 }} />
   <Marker  position={{ lat: 37.7455804, lng: -90.2622013}} /> 
    </GoogleMap>
));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add custom icon to each marker or you can also use strokeColor.

> Using icon:

```
<Marker
    
    icon={{
        url: myMarkerSVG,
        anchor: anchorPoint
    }}
    position={{ lat: 32.4695839, lng: -97.0587439 }}
/>
```

> Using icon with StrokeColor:

```
<Marker
    
    icon={{
        path: google.maps.SymbolPath.FORWARD_CLOSED_ARROW,
        strokeColor: "red",
        scale: 3
    }},
    position={{ lat: 32.4695839, lng: -97.0587439 }}
/>
```

and to resize the icon marker you use `scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(50, 50),`

Comment: icon props is wrongly passed to the second <Marker>